# How can I address class imbalance in a multinomial classification model with Tidymodels in R?

Tags: r, classification, tidymodels

I am struggling severly with a multinomial classification model in R.

I have a dataset of 1330 rows. I have two independent variables and one dependent variable.

The dependent variable (Category) has 337 unique values.

They are broken down into:

102 values
32 values
14 values
12 values
11 values
9 values
8 values
7 values
6 values
5 values (repeating until done)

I basically struggle with creating any model because they all throw warnings or errors about unbalanced levels in the training and test sets regarding the dependent variable.

I tried to add Category in the strata argument within initial_split, but it said "there is too little data to stratify"

I tried various resampling arguments within the recipe but none of them worked (see code).

What is the best way to address the problem I am facing with the dependent variable?

I understand that usually you want a full code example, but I feel like this is theoretical.

Thank you for any input you might have.

```
set.seed(123)

data_split <- initial_split(model_data, 
                            prop = 0.7, 
                            strata = Category)

training_set <- training(data_split) 
test_set <- testing(data_split)

model_recipe <- recipe(Category ~ ., data = training_set) %>%
  step_novel(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_numeric_predictors()) 
  # step_rose(Category)
  # step_downsample(Category)
  # step_smote(Category)
```

Comment: Theoretical Qs belong on CrossValidated.com

Comment: If you have levels of your outcome that only have, say, 5 examples, then a model algorithm is not going to be able to learn the characteristics of that level in a reliable way. Multiclass problems are in general *much* harder than those with two classes; for example, instead of one right plus one wrong answer, you will have one right plus 336 wrong answers. I recommend that you think of a new way to formulate the problem you are looking to solve because multiclass classification isn't going to be a good fit.

Comment: It is completely unrealistic to make a model with that many classes and such a small sample. The problem is not inbalance.